# Why the GN favicon?

Tags: discussion, design

Our current favicon:

[image]

Why does our favicon say **GN**? I understand the G, but why the N out of all the other letters in GENEALOGY?

Elsewhere on the network (such as the main [sites](https://stackexchange.com/sites) page) we have an icon that says **Gn**:

[image]

Still the n there, but looks a little less weird.

But this raises the question as to why we're not GFH, as that is more representative of our name. Obviously if we ever get to graduation then our icon would change, although there are some beta sites that do have a custom icon. Wonder if we can get a tree before Gardening & Landscaping SE take it...

Or maybe everyone likes our little [image] as it is?

Comment: I just want to assure everyone I'm not losing sleep over this, just been wondering for quite a while and never got around to posting it

Comment: I'd never paid attention to it. Now I'm curious. Are there any 3 letter favicons?

Comment: @PolyGeo Yes, HSM springs to mind, I'm sure there are others

Comment: I assumed it was the first two consonants for some reason. The Soundex code is too long -- it's G542. ;-)  Yes, if it has to be text, I'd like it to be GFH also.

Comment: How to get it changed: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/259897/215590

Answer (score 3):

I think GFH would be better than Gn (and then we could generously distract gardening with the tantalising prospect of GN while we steal the tree :) )